# Reset iframe's window object

Tags: javascript, html

I have an iframe, without any src specified.

I change the content dynamically with javascript using this code:

```
let doc = Paste.render_iframe.contentWindow.document

doc.open()
doc.write(Paste.get_value())
doc.close()
```

Which works. But the only problem is that if some javascript was used before, it stays inside the window object, and redefining them again causes errors.

I haven't found a way to reset/replace the iframe's window object.

What I did before was create a new iframe and replace the old one.

I could also try to change the src and then change the content.

The problem with those is that, 1) replacing iframes very often seems expensive, 2) I would have to deal with race conditions, having to check when iframe is fully loaded to accept new content.

So my question is, is there a way to replace or reset the iframe's window object without replacing it or modifying the src?

Comment: Can you isolate all the functionality and variables so it is all in one object or IIFE then overwrite that object?

Comment: Not sure how I could do that. Right now I just write html to the document. The html contains <script> tags with anything in it. And I can't force users to write the js in a certain way

Comment: Whole window would need to be replaced then once those script tags have been compiled. No magic way to reset a window other than load a new one

Answer (score 0):

Guess I'm going to try changing the src dynamically and waiting for the load event to change the content.

```
Paste.setup_render = function()
{
    Paste.render_iframe.addEventListener("load", function()
    {
        if(Paste.render_mode)
        {
            Paste.do_render()
        }
    })
}

Paste.reset_render_iframe = function()
{
    Paste.render_iframe.src = `about:blank?t=${Date.now()}_${Paste.get_random_string(4)}`
}

Paste.render = function()
{
    Paste.reset_render_iframe()
}

Paste.do_render = function()
{
    let doc = Paste.render_iframe.contentWindow.document

    doc.open()
    doc.write(Paste.get_value())
    doc.close()
}
```